# Why the sum value from mysql_fetch was double up?

Tags: mysql, fetch

I have an 2 database.

1 is `game_jnship_user`, 2 is `game_jnship_equip` and the data as below:

Here is `game_jnship_user`

```
+-----+-----------------+
| ID  | uid             |
+-----+-----------------+
| 1   | 50              |
+-----------------------+
```

Here is `game_jnship_equip`

```
+-----+------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID  | uid        | ebonus        | etype        |
+-----+------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1   | 50         | 100           | 1            |
| 2   | 50         | 10            | 1            |
| 3   | 50         | 120           | 2            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

And I query as below:

```
$_G['uid'] = '50';
$ushuxing = DB::query("SELECT sum(t2.ebonus) AS equipatk, sum(t3.ebonus) AS equipdef FROM ".DB::table('game_jnship_user')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." t2 ON (t1.uid = t2.uid AND t2.etype = '1') LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." t3 ON (t1.uid = t3.uid AND t3.etype = '2') WHERE t1.uid = $_G[uid]");
$rushuxing = DB::fetch($ushuxing);
```

After that, my output data as below:

```
$rushuxing[equipatk] = 110;
$rushuxing[equipdef] = 240;
```

Why the `$rushuxing[equipdef]` output is `240` not `120`?

Thank you.

Here is the raw MySQL query from the example above:

```
SELECT sum(t2.ebonus) AS equipatk, sum(t3.ebonus) AS equipdef
FROM game_jnship_user t1
LEFT JOIN game_jnship_equip t2
    ON (t1.uid = t2.uid AND t2.etype = '1')
LEFT JOIN game_jnship_equip t3
    ON (t1.uid = t3.uid AND t3.etype = '2')
WHERE t1.uid = '50'
```

Comment: I find your query hard to read.  Can you show us the raw MySQL query which you are trying to use?

Comment: I want sum the ebonus by etype and uid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The record having `etype = 2` is matched with 2 records having `etype = 1` in the `LEFT JOIN` operation, so you get 240 instead of 120.

You can use instead the following query that makes use of *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN etype = 1 THEN ebonus ELSE 0 END) AS equipatk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN etype = 2 THEN ebonus ELSE 0 END) AS equipdef
FROM game_jnship_equip
WHERE uid = 50
```

`GROUP BY uid` clause is not required since you are performing aggregation for a *specific* `uid` value.

Comment: no wonder, the `left join` got double `etype = 2`,  this solution solve my problem as well ! thank you !